# What are MPEG I, P and B frames?

Tags: video

I was recently going over MPEG articles and videos to understand how it works. I understand what I, P and B frames do but I do not understand how the prediction is calculated.
Assume that I want to record a video of a ball falling from the sky to the ground and then bouncing a couple of times before finally coming to a halt.
Also, I am not clear with the concept of the 16x16 macroblock.
Please tell me:

how prediction is calulated

what is macroblock and how it helps in MPEG encoding

My references:

[MPEG Prediction](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jac22/books/mm/book/node129.html)

[Video on MPEG conversion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7abyWT4dss)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer**:
Blocks are units for inter-frame comparison;
Prediction is based on amount of blocks presenting on both previous and following images;

**Longer answer**:
As input, a video encoder receives nothing else but a sequence of *frames*.
In most cases, the adjacent frames are *very similar* to each other, and the encoder attempts to figure out whether these frames are **indeed** similar.

How do you say if two images are similar?

- Both images are split into macroblocks (you can't compare entire images, they will certainly differ!)
- The algorithm attempts to find if a block from previous image exists on the following image (within a certain **proximity** to its original position)
- If, to a certain threshold, most of the blocks present on the following image, the following image is computed as a difference to the previous one (`P-frame`);

  - Of course, differing blocks are encoded as-is;
- If not, the following image is considered to belong to another scene, and there's no other way rather than keeping it entirely (`I-frame`).

In order to understand how prediction works, take a look at this image. It is created by a `deshaker` plug-in for `VirtualDub`, and used for a different purpose (detecting camera shakes), but it seems very representative:

[image: Deshaker]

The arrows indicate how the current image differs to the previous one;
The entire frame is split into macroblocks (larger than 16x16, however);
The difference for each block, compared to the previous image, is a *movement vector*;
As you see, most macroblocks (white arrows) follow the common pattern, and therefore they **can be encoded by only applying a transposition matrix to a previous frame**.
However, there are some blocks (red arrows) do not comply with the common pattern, and therefore **they must be encoded as-is**.
Of course, if everything is red, there's no choice other than encoding the entire frame as-is.